# Add tracking code to php echo link

Tags: php, hyperlink

I'm trying to add a Virtual Pageview to an activationlink that a customer gets when registering on my site. The working link is this:

```
a href="<?php echo $data['User']['activate_link'];?>" >Activate your account</a>.
```

Since I got my knowledge of php through trial and error, I've tried a lot of different combinations. Some combinations result in the e-mail not being sent at all, where others leave the whole website blank.

The link that seems to be working (but doesn't seem to track the virtual pageview) is now this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $data['User']['activate_link'];?>" onClick=”_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/activation']);”>Activate your account</a>
```

I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong near the ;?>" before onClick but everytime I delete or add something, the email stops working.

Comment: these `”` quotes are not correct try replacing them whith normal once `"`

Comment: Also I would advise you to get some structured knowledge (book or something). Messing with the code until it works - this is not a very reliable development strategy.

Comment: I've added the normal quotes, but now the same problem remains: the link is working but it's not adding the virtual pageview. It seems like the onClick bit is being ignored because the href is closed.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You're absolutely right. Until now everything was done by the webdeveloper. But because the activationlink doesn't provide good tracking (it redirects to the homepage immediately) which I only find out after going live, I'll have to fix it myself.